# What data type is used to store intermediate calculations while executing a program in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14

I was trying to do the following calculations but found out that the calculations do not yield the correct result. 
I have the following doubt that when my computer does the calculation a*b, what data type is used to store the result of the calculation temporary before doing the modulus. How is the data type in which it stores the result decided?. 
Please do let me know about the source of the information.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int a=1000000000000000000; // 18 zeroes
    long long int b=1000000000000000000;
    long long int c=1000000007; 
    long long int d=(a*b)%c;
    cout<<a<<"\n"<<b<<"\n"<<c<<"\n"<<d;
}
```

Edit1: This code also gives incorrect output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=1000000000; // 9 zeroes
    int b=1000000000;
    long long int c=1000000007; 
    long long int d=a*b%c;
    cout<<a<<"\n"<<b<<"\n"<<c<<"\n"<<d;
}
```

Comment: Maybe my understanding is wrong, but why would it need to store the result anywhere?

Comment: @Annabelle  I do not need to store the result, I just wanted to understand how calculations happen. For e.g. in the above case lets say a*b is calculated first so are results of any intermediate calculation directly typecasted to highest data type or is there some other mechanism?

Comment: Off-topic: Why would you include `<bits/stdc++.h>`?

Comment: @Holt I usually use the same template for writing all my codes. It's not needed here.

Comment: @Milan You should never have to include `<bits/stdc++.h>`. This is a compiler-specific header.

Comment: @Holt Oh, I see. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Annabelle, hope my edit1 makes the question clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the data type in which it stores the result decided?

The rules are fairly complicated and convoluted in general, but in this particular case it's simple. `a*b` is of type `long long`, and since `a*b` overflows the programs has Undefined Behavior.

You can use the equivalent formula to compute the correct result (without overflowing):

```
(a * b) % c == ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c
```

---

> Could you also suggest on how to decide for mixed data types and post
>   about your source of information

Of some interest: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion The standard rules are unfortunately even more complicated.

As some suggestions:

- never mix unsigned and signed.
- pay attentions that types smaller than int will be promoted to `int` or `unsigned`.
- for a type `T` equal or larger than `int` then `T op T` will have type type `T`. This is what you should be aiming for in your expressions. (i.e. have both operators of the same type either `int`, `long` or `long long`.
- avoid `unsigned` types. Unfortunately that's impossible with the current Standard Library design (`std::size_t` sigh)
- avoid `long` as its width differs between current major compilers and platforms
- if you care about the width of the integer data type then avoid `int` `long` `long long` and such and always use fixed width integer types (`std::int32_t` `std::int64_t` etc.). Completely ignore that technically those types are optional.

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a place where I can read the rules? 
Because suppose if I take a and b as int and make them equal to 1000000000 and do (a*b)%c, keeping c as long long int, will there be overflow again?

Comment: there is no integer type in C++ that can hold the result of your `a*b`

Comment: What about the example I gave in comment?

Comment: the result and data type of `a * b` is independent of the surrounding expression. If `a` is `int` and `b` is `int` then `a * b` is `int`. And `1000000000 * 1000000000` doesn't fit in an `int` and so you have overflow. You can force a `long long` result by casting at least one of the operands to `long long`, i.e. `static_cast<long long>(a) * b`. Again the surrounding expression is irrelevant. The type of `c` has absolutely no effect on the expression `a * b`

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot. Could you also suggest on how to decide for mixed data types and post about your source of information.

Comment: As far as avoiding unsigned types is concerned, context is all. In embedded systems, unsigned types are often preferred.

Comment: @user1671787 also in embedded systems as far as I know C++ is not preffered

Comment: The situation doesn't really depend on C vs C++. In any case, I haven't taken a survey on the popularity of C++ for embedded systems but there are some popular myths about its efficiency relative to C. If your embedded hardware resources are extremely limited (to the point where you wouldn't even consider using an OS), then in that case C might be a better choice. That's we did on my last embedded product (C and no OS) because we had only 4K of RAM and 64K of Flash. But that's a rare situation to be in.

Comment: And I forgot, no C++ compiler available for the Microcontroller we used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that long long has to be able to accommodate at least 64 bits but each 1000000000000000000 is a 60 bit number so a*b would yield a result that exceeds any integer representation the compiler supports. Perhaps you were thinking that the 1000000000000000000 was binary?

Comment: No, I did not want it to be binary, i just  wanted to understand whether the temporary storage of the calculation is also in the data type long long int or not.
For e.g. If I had a short int and short int calculation so will the storage be also in short int? and what about mixed data types?

Comment: OK, not binary. I just suggested it because I couldn't figure out why you would try to multiply numbers too large to avoid overflow. Looking at 'c' again, with its digit '7', I see my suggestion didn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you can read my comments on @bolov's post to understand further what I exactly wanted to know